# How to import a class from the test directory?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a project with

```
src/main/java/...
   /test/java/ ...
```

Now I made a `Utility` class in test. But for debugging I'd love to call its methods from main. Is that possible? I get Utility can't be resolved if I try to import the class in main. However when trying to create a class `Utility` in main, suddenly it complains that a duplicate class has been found. So it **can** see into the test directory!

Is there a possibility to access that class from test (which does not extend jUnit but is a regular class) from main?

Comment: No, classes in test aren't visible in main. It's the exact opposite - Classes in main are visible in test (so you can test them), which is why you're getting a duplicate class found message.